# Convert firefox (tab.id) to string

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to keep track of pragmatically opening tabs, but I am unable to
get the tab id in to the array, when i use `console.log(A)` it will give me readable output. but once i check inside the array it says `undefined` (B).

```
var urlArray= [];

function openNewUrl(newUrl)
{
    tabs.open({
        url: newUrl,
        onReady: function onReady(tab) {
            console.log(tab.id);       // ------> A
            urlArray[newUrl] = tab.id; // ------> B
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tab.id is a reference. When tab object is destroyed, tab.id becomes undefined.
Convert it to string and store in array.
ex: urlArray[newUrl]=tab.id.toString();